# Perl regular expression (starts with ATG and ends with TAG, TAA, or TGA)

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics

I need a regular expression in perl that will match with ATG at the start, and ends with either TAG, TAA, or TGA. This is the code I have so far.

```
my $sequence = 'AATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAAAAATACAGAATGATCTAACGAA';

while($sequence =~ ____) {
 print $1;
}
```

Comment: [`^ATG.*?(T(AG|AA|GA))$`](https://regex101.com/r/tUtg8J/1)

Comment: Your example doesn't match your requirements. Looks like you want to match DNA sequence though so maybe `^ATG[GTAC]+T(GA|AA|AG)$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're dealing with [codons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code) here, you probably forgot to mention that the nuclotides in between must be a multiple of 3.

**Code:**

```
my $sequence = 'AATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAAAAATACAGAATGATCTAACGAA';
               # |--------------1-------------|
               #                                        |---2---|  

while($sequence =~ /ATG(?:[ACTG]{3})*?T(?:A[AG]|GA)/g)
{
    print $&."\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
ATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAA
ATGATCTAA
```

**Description:**

- `ATG` - Matches "ATG" literally
- `(?:[ACTG]{3})*?` - is a [non capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), repeated 0 o more times, as few as possible ([lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), the extra `?`), matching:

  - `[ACTG]{3}` - 3 characters/nucleotides (either "A", "C", "T" or "G")
- `T(?:A[AG]|GA)` - matches "TAA", "TAG", or "TGA". Also, as [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078407/perl-regular-expression-starts-with-atg-and-ends-with-tag-taa-or-tga/40079783?noredirect=1#comment67444627_40079783), this can be written as `(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)` if you prefer to improve readability.

---

But if you also need to match **overlapping** sequences, you should use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent the match from consuming the characters.

**Code:**

```
               # modified to include overlapping sequences
my $sequence = 'AATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAAAAATATGGAATGATCTAACGAA';
               # |--------------1-------------|
               #                                   |---2---|
               #                                        |---3---|

while($sequence =~ /ATG(?=((?:[ACTG]{3})*?T(?:A[AG]|GA)))/g)
{
    print $&.$1."\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
ATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAA
ATGGAATGA
ATGATCTAA
```

---

And finally, this is a **more efficent** version of the last expression, using the [Unrolling the Loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) technique, that will yield better results when you're dealing with large sequences.

**Code:**

```
my $sequence = 'AATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAAAAATATGGAATGATCTAACGAA';
               # modified to include overlapping sequences

while($sequence =~ /ATG(?=((?:[ACG][ACTG]{2})*(?:T(?:A[CT]|G[CTG]|[CT][ACTG])(?:[ACG][ACTG]{2})*)*T(?:A[AG]|GA)))/g)
{
    print $&.$1."\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
ATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAA
ATGGAATGA
ATGATCTAA
```

Comment: I think that your `T(?:A[AG]|GA)` should be written as `(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)`, which is clearer and barely any longer. Perl will optimise the alternatives as a trie, so there will be no efficiency impact either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Borodin. I added your comment in the answer. I don't know why, though, I prefer `T(?:A[AG]|GA)`... I like to read it as "*a T followed by ...*".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this finds one match so it is non-exhaustive

```
my $sequence = 'AATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAAAAATACAGAATGATCTAACGAA';

if($sequence =~ /(ATG.*?(:?TAG|TAA|TGA))/) {
 print $1;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $sequence ='AATGGTTTCTCCCATCTCTCCATCGGCATAAAAATACAGAATGATCTAACGAA';
while($sequence =~m/ATG.*?(TGA|TAG|TAA)/g)
{
  print $&,"\n";
}
```